# SilverStripe class extensions in config.yml

Tags: php, silverstripe

I noticed that in some cases, when you write a class that extends an existing class, you need to declare the class extension in the config.yml file.

For example, I recently wrote this code to remove the "help" button in the CMS back-end.

**mysite/code/Tweak.php**

```
class Tweak extends LeftAndMainExtension
{
  public function init()
    {
      parent::init();
      /* Remove help link */
      CMSMenu::remove_menu_item('Help');
    }
}
```

**mysite/code/Config.yml**

```
LeftAndMain:
  extensions:
    - Tweak
```

**Question 1:** Why do some class extensions need to be declared in config.yml? And why is this extra step not necessary for other class extensions (eg extending DataObject or Page_Controller)?

**Question 2:** Specific question about above code, why am I declaring *Tweaks* as an extension to *LeftAndMain* in the config file, but in the php file I'm actually extending *LeftAndMainExtension*?

Comment: What is an example where you **don't** need to declare the extension in config? Extensions don't automatically assign themselves to classes…

Comment: Well such an example would be: `Class HomePage_Controller extends Page_Controller` is it not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Question 1**: Why do some class extensions need to be declared in config.yml? And why is this extra step not necessary for other class extensions (eg extending DataObject or Page_Controller)?

There's an important distinction here between PHP and SilverStripe terminology.

In SilverStripe, an *Extension* is a framework feature that is implemented in SilverStripe which allows you to modify the behaviour of an Object without having access to anything other than what's public. It's similar to Ruby in this respect.

In PHP, you use the `extends` keyword to define a sub-class of an existing class.

In your example you're using the `LeftAndMainExtension`, which is a SilverStripe "Extension" - this lets you modify the behaviour of the CMS menu in SilverStripe's admin area, while it doesn't *literally extend (in PHP terms) the `LeftAndMain` class*.

> **Question 2**: Specific question about above code, why am I declaring *Tweaks* as an extension to *LeftAndMain* in the config file, but in the php file I'm actually extending *LeftAndMainExtension*?

As above, this is how SilverStripe's extension system works. It basically follows the following process:

- You create a class that `extends` (PHP keyword) `Extension` at some point in the inheritance (you use `LeftAndMainExtension`, which extends `Extension`). For DataObjects you use `DataExtension` instead.
- You tell SilverStripe to apply *your Extension* to a Object, in this case it's `LeftAndMain`

The naming is deliberate so you can group Objects and their relevant Extensions together easily/visually:

> Convention is for extension class names to end in Extension. This isn't a requirement but makes it clearer
>
> - *SilverStripe developer documentation*

Note I've been deliberately capitalising Extension to denote that it is a SilverStripe Extension class, not a PHP extension of a class (`class Foo extends Bar`).

---

For an example of how the framework performs this process, it's basically like this:

- Object is initialized
- Framework analyses YAML config (or Extensions applied via `Object::add_extension()`) for extensions
- Framework loops extensions, setting `$this->owner` as the current Object so extensions can access **public methods and properties** from it
- Framework returns final Object

[More info here.](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/extending/extensions/)

Comment: dammit Robbie, you beat me by a minute! :-P

Comment: Very descriptive answer, thank you. So basically the reason that extending eg `Page_Controller` is *hassle free* whereas extending `LeftAndMain` needs this workaround (via **E**xtension and yaml declaration), has to do with class property access / permissions? IE `LeftAndMain` is more protected from altering than `Page_Controller`?

Comment: Correct- the Extension system is designed to protect the core framework, unfortunately its often more of a problem since PHP developers are used to standard inheritance so people like me find it quite restrictive

Answer (score 8):

You are actually talking about two basic OO patterns here.

1. Simple subclassing

This is pretty much the standard way in many languages including PHP and Java for a custom class to inherit some logic from another class and be able to declare its own ala:

```
class MyObject extends DataObject {
}
```

There is nothing specific to SilverStripe in this, it's native (PHP) in this case.

2. The Decorator

When you subclass `Extension` or any one of its subclasses e.g. `DataExtension`, `SiteTreeExtension` or `LeftAndMainExtension` as per your example, you're "decorating" an existing class and the current library's or framework's implementation of the "Decorator" pattern.

In SilverStripe a big difference between these two approaches is that for subclassing, your new class will create a new table in the database (where you declare a `$db` static in it). Using the decorator (An `Extension` subclass declared in YML or via the `$extension` static in the class itself) a new table is not created, you're simply able to "tack-on" new fields and logic onto existing objects and their tables.

A common example of the utility of the later approach is the `Member` class. Subclassing it, won't help you much in modifying / customising SilverStripe's membership and permissions system, *Decorating it* will.

See the dedicated page on this feature of SilverStripe: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/